# Sum columns duration/days and duration/hours

Tags: org-mode, org-table

In my org file I have the table:

```
|   | Start date             | End date               | State | Task     | Duration/days | Duration (hours) |
|---+------------------------+------------------------+-------+----------+---------------+------------------|
| # | <2018-01-02 Wed 10:30> | <2018-01-02 Wed 12:00> | Taken | some url |        0.0625 |         01:30:00 |
| # | <2018-01-02 Wed 14:00> | <2018-01-02 Wed 18:00> | Taken | some url |      0.166667 |         04:00:00 |
| # | <2018-01-03 Tue 10:30> | <2018-01-03 Wed 12:00> | Taken | some url |        0.0625 |         01:30:00 |
| # | <2018-01-03 Thu 13:30> | <2018-01-03 Thu 18:00> | Taken | some url |        0.1875 |         04:30:00 |
|---+------------------------+------------------------+-------+----------+---------------+------------------|
|   |                        |                        |       |          |               |                  |

#+TBLFM: $6=date(<$3>)-date(<$2>)::$7=60*60*24*$6;T
```

I have a formula to calculate duration. Nice.

But also I need formulas for total sums in columns `Duration/days` and `Duration/hours`

So result must be like this:

```
|   | Start date             | End date               | State | Task     | Duration/days | Duration (hours) |
|---+------------------------+------------------------+-------+----------+---------------+------------------|
| # | <2018-01-02 Wed 10:30> | <2018-01-02 Wed 12:00> | Taken | some url |        0.0625 |         01:30:00 |
| # | <2018-01-02 Wed 14:00> | <2018-01-02 Wed 18:00> | Taken | some url |      0.166667 |         04:00:00 |
| # | <2018-01-03 Tue 10:30> | <2018-01-03 Wed 12:00> | Taken | some url |        0.0625 |         01:30:00 |
| # | <2018-01-03 Thu 13:30> | <2018-01-03 Thu 18:00> | Taken | some url |        0.1875 |         04:30:00 |
|---+------------------------+------------------------+-------+----------+---------------+------------------|
|   |                        |                        |       |          |      0.479167 |         11:30:00 |
```

Comment: I have added a very general solution there: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46862/2370. There you do not need the duration in days anymore and you can add org time durations to get the total duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following formulas work:

```
#+TBLFM: $6=date(<$3>)-date(<$2>)::$7=60*60*24*$6;T :: @>$6 = vsum(@I..@II) :: @>$7 = vsum(@I..@II);T
```

`vsum` is a calc function that adds the components of a 'vector' (here the contents of a column between the first and second hline separators). The last column needs a T format to tell calc that these are HMS values. `@>$6` is org mode notation for the last row of column 6. See the [References](https://orgmode.org/manual/References.html#References) section in the org mode manual for more examples.

Comment: Is it possible to calc amount of hours WITHOUT column "Duration/days"?