# How do I reference a columnview table

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I'm trying to get effort estimates out of a columnview table and do some math on it in a separate table.

```
#+NAME: estimate
#+BEGIN: columnview :indent t
| ITEM             | TODO | Effort | CLOCKSUM |
|------------------+------+--------+----------|
| \_    Some task  |      | 40:00  |          |
#+END:

| Effort |
|--------|
| #ERROR |
#+TBLFM: @2$1=remote(estimate, @2,$3)
```

I have tried moving the tblname down in the block, which doesn't work either.

Update after fix:

```
#+NAME: estimate
#+BEGIN: columnview :indent t
| ITEM             | TODO | Effort | CLOCKSUM |
|------------------+------+--------+----------|
| \_    Some task  |      |  40:00 |          |
#+END:

| Effort |
|--------|
|  40.00 |
#+TBLFM: @2$1=remote(estimate, @2$3);t
```

Comment: Yes, right. With sole durations in table cells the table formula modifier `;t` works too. It only becomes more complicated if you want to directly calculate with durations without intermediate table columns containing working hours. That was [one of the issues at the other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta/46862#comment72160_46860).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is a simple typo. The comma separating `@2,$3` must be removed in the `TBLFM`.

The second problem is that you use Orgmode time strings `40:00`. To be able to further process that time duration you must use Calc durations, i.e., `40@ 0" 0'` for 40 hours, 0 minutes and 0 seconds (seconds are optional).

`org-table-filters` in the section *More complicated but very general solution* from my answer to [some other question here on Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/46862/2370) enable you to work with Orgmode time durations instead of Calc durations.

**Hint**:
I easily identified the problems with your formula by switching the org table formula debugger on (Checkbox `Debug Formulas` in the `Tbl`-menu of Orgmode).