# Calculating with timestamps in org-mode tables

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Emacs 26.1

```
|   | Start date             | End date               | State | Task     | Duration (hours) |
|---+------------------------+------------------------+-------+----------+------------------|
| # | <2018-01-02 Wed 10:30> | <2018-01-02 Tue 14:00> | Taken | some url |         00:00:00 |
| # | <2018-01-02 Wed 14:00> | <2018-01-02 Wed 18:00> | Taken | some url |         00:00:00 |
| # | <2018-01-03 Wed 10:00> | <2018-01-03 Wed 12:00> | Taken | some url |         00:00:00 |
| # | <2018-01-03 Wed 14:00> | <2018-01-03 Wed 18:00> | Taken | some url |         00:00:00 |
|---+------------------------+------------------------+-------+----------+------------------|
|   |                        |                        |       |          |         00:00:00 |

#+TBLFM: $6=60*60*24*date(<$3>)-date(<$2>);T :: @>$6 = vsum(@I..@II);T
```

But as you can see the last column (**Duration**) not calculate.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

The `t`, `T`, and `U` flags expect an input value in the format HH:MM:SS, not a time stamp. Time stamps are an org-mode invention, so org-mode knows how to deal with them without any special flags. Also, you can't have a space between the bottom of your table and the `#TBLFM:` directive. Finally, if you want to convert a value in days to a value in hours, you only need to multiply it by 24, not by 24*60*60 (which converts days to seconds).

Taken together, I think what you need is:

```
|   | Start date             | End date               | State | Task     | Duration (hours) |
|---+------------------------+------------------------+-------+----------+------------------|
| # | <2018-01-02 Wed 10:30> | <2018-01-02 Tue 14:00> | Taken | some url |         3.499992 |
| # | <2018-01-02 Wed 14:00> | <2018-01-02 Wed 18:00> | Taken | some url |         4.000008 |
| # | <2018-01-03 Wed 10:00> | <2018-01-03 Wed 12:00> | Taken | some url |         1.999992 |
| # | <2018-01-03 Wed 14:00> | <2018-01-03 Wed 18:00> | Taken | some url |         4.000008 |
|---+------------------------+------------------------+-------+----------+------------------|
|   |                        |                        |       |          |             13.5 |
#+TBLFM: $6=24 * ($3-$2) :: @>$6 = vsum(@I..@II)
```

Comment: I was also thinking about it. I came up with '$6=time($3-$2)' do you have an idea how to show the result as 'HH:MM:SS'?

Comment: @jue from calc the format of HMS output is controlled by the function `calc-hms-notation`. I'm not sure how to apply that to an org-table

Comment: @jue see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta/46862#46862

Comment: @Tyler I need to show duration in format HH:MM:SS

Comment: you asked why your formula wasn't getting calculated, that's what I answered. you have asked how to get HH:MM:SS in another question, and that question has two good answers already: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta/46862#46862