# Time-formatted output from org-table date- and time calculation?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs, org-table, time-date, calc

I have an org-table for my timesheets. Part of it looks this:

```
| Start              | End                    | End - Start |
| <2020-03-05 10:00> | <2020-03-05 Thu 14:30> |      0.1875 |
#+TBLFM: $3=$2-$1
```

## How can I get that "0.1875" to turn into "4:30"?

- (Spac)emacs/calc/org-mode has undestood that they are dates (org-toggle-time-stamp-overlays works on them and the colours change). Perhaps this is the

  > algorithm generally “does the right thing”

  from [Free-Form Dates](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Free_002dForm-Dates.html#Free_002dForm-Dates) <- [Date Formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Date-Formats.html#Date-Formats) <- [Display Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Display-Modes.html#Display-Modes) <- [Mode Settings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Mode-Settings.html#Mode-Settings) <- [Calc-manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/index.html#Top)
- And the subtraction is correct (24 hours * 0.1875 = 4.5 hours)
- But it gives me the duration as a decimal number of a 24 hour day, as per

  > Subtracting two date forms computes the number of days between them (**represented as a simple number**)

  from [Date Forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Date-Forms.html#Date-Forms) <- [Data Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Data-Types.html#Data-Types) <- [Calc-manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/index.html#Top)

## Options

- `"floor($3*24)`
  to get just the hours, and then separate out the minutes, get the result into the same cell, perhaps even with the formatting I want. Ugly, and seems unnecessary. The software already has some understanding of dates
- `time($2-$1)` - I just happened to try this right before starting to write this post. `floor` had worked, so why not?

`| Start              | End                    | time(End - Start) |
| <2020-03-05 10:00> | <2020-03-05 Thu 14:30> | 4@ 30' 0"         |`

`#+TBLFM: $3=time($2-$1)`

That's more like it. I recognise this format. It's mentioned in [HMS Forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/HMS-Forms.html) <- [Data Types](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Data-Types.html#Data-Types) <- [Calc-manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/index.html#Top)

And `time` is one of the functions from the [Index of Algebraic Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Function-Index.html)

Now *in* [HMS Forms](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/HMS-Forms.html), it says

> Display format for HMS forms is quite flexible. See [HMS Formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/HMS-Formats.html#HMS-Formats)

[HMS Formats](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/HMS-Formats.html#HMS-Formats) <- [Display Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Display-Modes.html#Display-Modes) <- [Mode Settings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Mode-Settings.html#Mode-Settings) <- [Calc-manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/index.html#Top)

> The [(calc-hms-notation)] command controls the display of HMS (hours-minutes-seconds) forms. It prompts for a string which consists basically of an “hours” marker, optional punctuation, a “minutes” marker, more optional punctuation, and a “seconds” marker. Punctuation is zero or more spaces, commas, or semicolons. The hours marker is one or more non-punctuation characters. The minutes and seconds markers must be single non-punctuation characters.

But entering these seems to have no effect. I've tried
`hms` No change

`h;m;s` No change

`hh, mm, ss` which gives error "Bad hours-minutes-seconds format"

`hh;mm;ss` which also does, so maybe it's the double h

`h;mm;ss` this one too, so maybe it's the double anything

No changes at all, which makes me think I've messed up somewhere else. I've restarted Spacemacs as well, and that didn't help.

---

It seems to me that I should not use org-mode's [Durations and time values](https://orgmode.org/manual/Durations-and-time-values.html#Durations-and-time-values), because

> Input duration values must be of the form ‘HH:MM[:SS]’

and I want time and date to be in the same cell. I sometimes work past midnight

---

Somewhat related:

[Calculating with timestamps in org-mode tables](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47190/calculating-with-timestamps-in-org-mode-tables)

[Org mode time sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26063545/org-mode-time-sheet)

---

#### Edit 8mar2020:

[Table formula for dates delta](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta) is similar. I'd say this question is different in that I ask whether HH:MM is possible without an extra day-column, and without editing (spac)emacs' config.

Comment: Duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta/46862#46862 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table formula for dates delta](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta)

Comment: Almost. Is it possible to get HH:MM(:SS) without the days-column? (Same question a_subscriber had in 46859). I prefer a solution without adding to config so much that I'd either stay with the ```time($2-$1)```-solution, or have an extra column for day

Comment: Emacs is all about writing additional code into your config. There is no ready made solution for every special problem. If you think it is important for many people, you could contribute the known solution to the org-mode project.     Anyways: If you don't want to put this code into your config, you could embed that code into the org-file itself. Put it into a `emacs-lisp` source block, give that block a name and use that name from within your table formula.