# Org-mode spreadsheet time diff elisp formula or GNU Calc

Tags: org-mode, parse-time, spreadsheet, formula

I wish to substract from a start time an end time in my org-mode spreadsheet. My times strings look like this (only the inline code):

- starttime: `9:42` or `09:42`
- endtime: `18:20`

So it's 24h format.

I wrote the following functions in my `init.el`:

```
;; TIME TRACKING

;; NOTE: The following functions are used for time tracking in
;; org-mode spreadsheets! That is why they might be a bit specific.
(defun fill-time-tuple (time-tuple fill)
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (or x fill))
          time-tuple))

(defun seconds-to-hours-and-minutes (seconds)
  (let ((hours (/ seconds 3600)))
    (let ((remaining-seconds (- seconds (* 3600 hours))))
      (let ((minutes (/ remaining-seconds 60)))
        (list hours minutes)))))

(defun time-tuple-diff (time-tup-start time-tup-end)
  (truncate
   (float-time
    (time-subtract (apply #'encode-time (fill-time-tuple time-tup-start 0))
                   (apply #'encode-time (fill-time-tuple time-tup-end 0))))))
```

With this, I evaluated the functions and also restarted Emacs, to make sure the functions are defined. However, the following table still gives an error, when I try to make use of the functions:

```
| _ |       | starttime | updatetime | endtime | spenttime |
| # | times |      9:28 |      18:20 |    9:10 | #ERROR    |
#+TBLFM: @2$5=$updatetime::@2$6='(seconds-to-hours-and-minutes (time-tuple-diff (parse-time-string $endtime) (parse-time-string $starttime)))
```

Specifically, if I debug:

```
Substitution history of formula
Orig:   '(seconds-to-hours-and-minutes (time-tuple-diff (parse-time-string $endtime) (parse-time-string $starttime)))
$xyz->  '(seconds-to-hours-and-minutes (time-tuple-diff (parse-time-string 9:10) (parse-time-string 9:28)))
@r$c->  '(seconds-to-hours-and-minutes (time-tuple-diff (parse-time-string 9:10) (parse-time-string 9:28)))
$1->    '(seconds-to-hours-and-minutes (time-tuple-diff (parse-time-string 9:10) (parse-time-string 9:28)))
Result: #ERROR
Format: NONE
Final:  #ERROR
```

My guess is, that somehow the functions I defined are not available to spreadsheet calculation.

This is my guess, because the code actually works inside a source block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp
(seconds-to-hours-and-minutes
 (time-tuple-diff
  (parse-time-string "10:30")
  (parse-time-string "09:20")))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| 1 | 10 |
```

How can I get my functions working for the spreadsheet formula evaluation?

Alternatively I could live with a simple GNU Calc formula to substract times. That is what I was initially looking for, but could not find. Then I switched to "OK I'll write an Elisp formula then!"

Comment: There are multiple gotchas here: note the `9:10` entry e.g. It is supposed to be a copy of `18:20` but it isn't. Calc interprets it as a ratio and simplifies it to lowest terms!  There are similar potholes in all of this. You are probably better off using active dates in your table entries. See e.g. [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta).

Comment: @NickD I tried that and you are right, much less cumbersome that way and I will go with that for now. If you made your comment into an answer, I could after some time, provided no one else solves this particular problem, accept it as an answer.

Comment: BTW, you can also use  passive dates (e.g. `[2020-05-28 Thu 09:18]`) as well as active dates (e.g.  `<2020-05-28 Thu 09:18>`). The latter might cause problems if the file is e.g. an agenda file: you'll find all sorts of entries in your agenda!

Comment: As for an answer, I can describe some of the peculiarities that plague Org mode spreadsheets. Is that what you meant? Other than that, I don't think that there is anything wrong with your functions: it's just that the somewhat mysterious type conversions that Org mode and Calc do, make this approach unwieldy. So the answer is probably "Don't do that!" - use the methods described in the linked question (particularly in the answer by Tobias).