# formatting a org-table formula result

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I would like to calculate the time in this table:

```
| Start                 | End                   |       Sum | Second Sum |
|-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------+------------|
| [2021-03-12 Fr 10:00] | [2021-03-12 Fr 11:00] | 3599.9424 |      00:59 |
#+TBLFM: $3=($2-$1)*24*60*60::$4=$3;U
```

The `;U` flag to format the value as time only works if I save the result in a temporary column (also there is one second missing somehow).

I would like to calculate the time in one step, but it does not work for me:

```
| Start                 | End                   |   Sum | Second Sum |
|-----------------------+-----------------------+-------+------------|
| [2021-03-12 Fr 10:00] | [2021-03-12 Fr 11:00] | 00:00 | #ERROR     |
#+TBLFM: $3=($2-$1)*24*60*60;U::$4=$3
```

How can I find out what is wrong here?

Comment: The conversions that Org mode does when evaluating formulas in a table are, to say the least, arcane. The best advice I can offer is that whenever Org mode seems obstreperous, you write a lisp function to do the evaluation, the way *you* want  it. See e.g https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta/46862#46862,

Comment: Thank you for the assessment, Nick! This will go right on to my TODO-list as I have just stared to learn writing functions in elisp. Do you know if a change in this matter is on the roadmap of org-mode devs?