# How to calculate velocity (units divided by time in HH:MM format) in org-table formula

Tags: org-mode, org-table

Let's say I have two tasks with some duration in HH:MM format and value (points). I'd like to calculate the velocity (you can think of points as km and time in hours, you get km/h)

```org
| task |     time | points | velocity |
|------+----------+--------+----------|
| A    |     0:45 |      2 | 2/0      |
| B    |     1:30 |      1 | 30       |
| Sum  | 02:15:00 |        | #ERROR   |
#+TBLFM: @4$2=vsum(@2..@3);T::$4=$3/$2
```

I can easily sum the duration adding `;T` at the end of the sum formula (`@4$2=vsum(@2..@3);T`). However, the division of a number (the `points` in column 3) by a time in `HH:MM` format (`$4=$3/$2`) doesn't work out of the box.

How can I do it?

Comment: In the final row, `$3` is not defined, so `$2/$3` does not make sense. Did you mean to specify it somehow?

Comment: Divide points by time? That does not make any sense to me. What do the "points" represent, what does the time represent and what are you trying to calculate?

Comment: @NickD it's a velocity measure. Think of points as of km. You made 20 km in 0:20 hours (i.e. in 20 minutes), your velocity ("ratio") is 60. With time duration and points is common in project management (prioritisation is given to the task with higher velocity).

Comment: I was wondering about that. You should add that description in your question: if you had, we would  not need all this discussion to get here.

Comment: You should also edit your question to fix it: ATM it's very misleading because the description ("... the division of HH:MM format by a number...") is the exact opposite of the operation (`$3/$2`).

Comment: You might get some inspiration from [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta) and @Tobias's answer in particular. I think your best bet is to do the conversions yourself using lisp formulas.

Comment: I edited your question to fix up the confusing part that I pointed out in a comment above and also recalculated your table to conform to current reality. You need to do that yourself in the future: posting a confusing question and *not fixing it* will likely result in the question being closed - probably with a reason like "Needs details or clarity". You should also make sure that my edits are not misrepresenting your intentions (which is why it's preferable that *you* edit the question and fix its shortcomings).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the structure of the division so time/number give a result if you add `;T`.

Instead of $3/$2 (ratio/time), try $2/$3 (time/ratio):

```
| task |     time | points |    ratio |
| ---- | -------- | ------ | -------- |
| A    |     0:45 |      2 | 00:22:30 |
| B    |     1:30 |      1 | 01:30:00 |
| Sum  | 02:15:00 |        | 01:52:30 |
#+tblfm: @4$2=vsum(@2$2..@3$2);T::@3$4=$2/$3;T::@4$4=vsum(@2$4..@3$4);T
```

Comment: actually, $3/$2 instead of $2/$3 was a typo, sorry for that, in the table formula is was $2/$3. ";T" at the end of the formula worked indeed (i thought i tried it out). Thanks for the answer.

Comment: It's not quite clear what the OP really wants, but the basic error in his formula is that `$3` is not defined in the final row. You have modified his formula to something else, so I'm not sure you are answering his question - although the fact that he has accepted your answer has confused me :-)

Comment: @NickD thanks for formatting the tables. Looks like even without specifying $3 in the last row, the formula fills in $4 all the rows but the final one (for which it throws an error).

Comment: The formula in the answer is different from the formula in the question, so I'm not sure which formula you are talking about.

Comment: @NickD actually, you were right that it wasn't clear that OP wants. I actually want to divide points by hour (I'll correct the question), and this doesn't work with ;T at the end of the division formula.