# Floor timestamp to nearest quarter in the hour

Tags: org-table

How to floor timestamps to their nearest quarter in the hour in an org-table. I can't seem to convert the stamps to only minutes to do calculations. Or is there another way?

```
| start | floored |
|-------+---------|
| 10:20 |   10:15 |
| 07:58 |   07:45 |
| 07:38 |   07:30 |
| 07:40 |   07:30 |
| 08:30 |   08:30 |
```

I've worked a bit more at the problem and I have now this. Almost, converting back to `HH:MM` does not work.

```lisp
(defun hm-to-minutes (str)
  (let* ((lst (split-string str ":"))
         (hour (car lst))
         (minute (cadr lst)))
    (+ (* (string-to-number hour) 60)
       (string-to-number minute))))

(defun hm-get-minutes (str)
  (string-to-number (cadr (split-string str ":"))))

(defun minutes-to-hm (minutes)
  (concat (number-to-string (/ minutes 60))
          ":"
          (number-to-string (% minutes 60))))
```

```
| start |     |    |    |     | floored |
|-------+-----+----+----+-----+---------|
| 10:20 | 620 | 20 |  5 | 615 | #ERROR  |
| 07:58 | 478 | 58 | 13 | 465 | #ERROR  |
| 07:38 | 458 | 38 |  8 | 450 | #ERROR  |
| 07:40 | 460 | 40 | 10 | 450 | #ERROR  |
| 08:30 | 510 | 30 |  0 | 510 | #ERROR  |
#+TBLFM: $2='(hm-to-minutes $1)
#+TBLFM: $3='(hm-get-minutes $1)
#+TBLFM: $4=$3%15
#+TBLFM: $5=$2-$4
#+TBLFM: $6='(minutes-to-hm $5)
```

Is there a way to also do this without the intermediate columns?

Comment: Related answer that might give you some ideas: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/46859/table-formula-for-dates-delta/46862#46862 - note that `HH:MM` is generally NOT a good format to use in Org tables: it is much easier to do calculations with Org timestamps.

Comment: @NickD sadly `HH:MM` is the format that's available to me. Once in the table I could convert them to org timestamps if that makes my live easier to me.

Comment: You can combine all the calculations into a single function, although the intermediate columns are good for debugging. The problem with column 6 is that despite appearances, the argument to `minutes-to-hm` is a string, not a number. Do `C-c {` to enable formula debugging and try it out to see. BTW, when you do combine everything into a single function, you wouldn't have the conversion problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an all-in-one function, using two of your functions for the conversions:

```el
  (defun hm-to-minutes (str)
    (let* ((lst (split-string str ":"))
           (hour (car lst))
           (minute (cadr lst)))
      (+ (* (string-to-number hour) 60)
         (string-to-number minute))))

  (defun minutes-to-hm (minutes)
    (concat (format "%02d" (/ minutes 60))
            ":"
            (format "%02d" (% minutes 60))))

  (defun my/quarter-floor (hmstr)
    (let* ((tmins (hm-to-minutes hmstr))
            (hrs (/ tmins 60))
            (mins (- tmins (* hrs 60)))
            (rmins (- tmins (% mins 15))))
      (minutes-to-hm rmins)))
```

You can use it like this:

```org
| start | floored |
|-------+---------|
| 10:20 |   10:15 |
| 07:58 |   07:45 |
| 07:38 |   07:30 |
| 07:40 |   07:30 |
| 08:30 |   08:30 |
#+TBLFM: $2 = '(my/quarter-floor $1)
```

I modified your `minutes-to-hm` to use `format`, instead of `number-to-string`, which allows easy zero-padding on the left to produce `HH:MM` format, with two-digit `HH` and `MM` fields always.